# How can I work out if windows 7 is scheduled to shutdown/restart at a particular time (System admin people force shutdowns/restarts)

Tags: windows, windows-services

I am in a situation where the sys admins sometimes force our teams windows 7 server to shutdown/restart some nights. 
They don't give us any warning of this, so it means we come in the next morning with all our overnight jobs not having run.

What would be very helpful for us is if we could check, say at 3pm each day via a registry setting(or something else) if it will be shutdown/restarted.

Questions:

1. Is there a registry setting that we can check to see if it is scheduled to restart/shutdown
2. Is there anyway to prevent a restart/shutdown if we detect from (1) that it will be restarted/shutdown

Thanks

Comment: Even if you could block the sysadmin from restarting, that is probably not a healthy career choice.  If you are running an overnight job why not be proactive and email your sysadmin to tell them that you are running an overnight job and not to restart the system.  You can't force them to communicate effectively but you can do it yourself

Comment: The typical reason admins force restarts is to ensure that Windows updates are promptly installed. You can prevent this by making sure that when you get notification of updates, you install them and restart yourself on your own schedule. Windows will no longer need to be restarted, and the admin won't need to force it. (We have a group policy in effect that says that if updates exist and haven't been done by Thursday at 10AM on user's desktop machines, the system is force-rebooted.  Servers delay until Saturday at 10AM to give time to do it off-hours, but will be rebooted if we don't.

Comment: Thanks for the comments guys. Unfortunately for us we are in an organisation where the sys admins will take no notice of our requests (been down that path many times) to let us know when there will be a reboot/shutdown.  So even something as simple as us putting in place an automated script that would run each day at say 3pm that would inform us of a reboot/shutdown that night would be helpful since then we can do the reboot at 3pm.